Drission page DrissionPage.errors.ElementNotFoundError element not found
when using sessionpage from DrissionPage it wont send me the elements text, but when using selenium it works fine, have used sessionpage on other websites and can find element fine, but not on this one why?
how to find elements on drission
from DrissionPage import SessionPage
import time
page = SessionPage()
page.get('https://onlyfans.com/u425183820')
time.sleep(5)
items = page.ele('xpath://div[@class="b-profile-status mw-100 m-separator g-nowrap d-flex align-items-center justify-content-start"]').text
print(items)

error i get
    raise ElementNotFoundError(None, self.method, self.args)
DrissionPage.errors.ElementNotFoundError: 
没有找到元素。
method: ele()
args: {'locator': 'xpath://div[@class="b-profile-status mw-100 m-separator g-nowrap d-flex align-items-center justify-content-start"]', 'index': 1}

want the text of element to be found which would be
"Seen Jun 20"

The xpath you wrote is incorrect. I don't know what you are looking for.

its not, run it in selenium and it works fine but not in Drission
that is what i am looking for  = want the text of element to be found which would be
"Seen Jun 20"
